# Download PDF from Base64 string

Tags: php, pdf, base64

---

My situation (all in PHP):

What I get: A Base64 encoded string from an API.

What I want: A link to click on that downloads this document as an PDF. (I am sure it will always be a PDF file)

I have tried this:

```
    $decoded = base64_decode($base64);
    file_put_contents('invoice.pdf', $decoded);
```

but I am kind off lost, can't seem to find a way to download it after decoding it.

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The example here seems helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

In your case:

```
<?php
$decoded = base64_decode($base64);
$file = 'invoice.pdf';
file_put_contents($file, $decoded);

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

This should force the download to occur.

Comment: Thankyou! This solved my problem. I am now facing the fact the my PDF file is corrupt and I get "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by" if I put it inside a link, but I should be able to found a way around that. I'll post the answer once I got it for other people. If you have any tips let me know, thanks again!

Comment: Thank you so much. I added this line of code unlink($file); before 'exit;' because I don't want the file to be stored in the server forever.

Answer (score 10):

Don't need to decode base64. You can send header with binary file.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($filedata));
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $filedata;
exit;
```

Comment: This solution works flawless and saved my life ! Thanks !